# How to integrate market depth chart using highchart?

Tags: jquery, highcharts

How to implement market depth chart using area chart  [Example image click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/INyme.png)

Can any one help me, I need live below chart

i have tried below code using high chart , X,Y points started in legit site how to set the point in center in graph.

```
  <html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Depth Chart</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
    $(function () {
    $.getJSON('http://localhost/bitcocyrus/market_depth/1', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    $('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
    type: 'area'
    },
    title: {
    text: 'Market depth'
    },
    subtitle: {
    text: ''
    },
    xAxis: {
    allowDecimals: true,
    labels: {
    formatter: function () {
    return this.value; // clean, unformatted number for year
    }
    }
    },
    yAxis: {
    title: {
    text: 'Volume'
    },
    labels: {
    formatter: function () {
    return this.value ;
    }
    }
    },
    tooltip: {
    pointFormat: '{point.y} BTC at {point.x} CNY'
    },
    plotOptions: {
    area: {
    marker: {
    enabled: false,
    symbol: 'circle',
    radius: 2,
    states: {
    hover: {
    enabled: true
    }
    }
    }
    }
    },
    series: [{ name: 'ask', data: data.buy_order }, { name: 'bid', data: data.sell_order }]
    });
    });
    });
    //]]>
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="//code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
    <div id="container"></div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Please check the below json formate

```
{"buy_order":"[1]","sell_order":"[1,10]"}
```

Comment: Your questions is too broad to warrant an answer.  Can you post what you have tried?

Comment: I have given above code @Sid

Comment: I would use [`series.zones`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.area.zones). Simple example for you: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/bfsh9u00/

Answer (score 0):

Use below solution and it completely work.

1. you need cumulative sum of buy order amount or unit which is order by buy order price in ascending order.
2. again you need cumulative sum of sell order amount or unit which is order by sell order price in descending order.

   combine the result of 1 and 2 in one query
3. use this code to create high chart.

function DepthChart(apilink, base,counter){
$.getJSON(apilink + '/Chart/depthchart?Base=' +base + '&Counter=' +counter + '&Depth=100',  function (depthChartJSON) {

```
    $(function () {
        $('#depthgraphContainer').highcharts({
            chart: {
                backgroundColor: "#000d1d",
                marginTop: 75,
                type: 'area',
                animation: true,
                marginBottom: 100,
                marginLeft: 100,
                marginRight: 100,
                marginTop: 100,
                zoomType: 'x',
                // spacingLeft: 100,
                // spacingRight: 100,
                // spacingTop: 100,
                // spacingBottom: 100
            },

            title: {
                text: '',
                //y: 40
            },

            // subtitle: {
            //     text: 'Drag mouse to zoom'
            // },

            navigator: {
                enabled: false
            },

            scrollbar: {
                enabled: false
            },
            exporting: {
                enabled: false
            },

            xAxis: {
                gridLineWidth: 0.1,
                // tickPixelInterval:500,
                // minorTickInterval: 'auto',
                // minorTickColor: '#FEFEFE',
                // title: {
                //     text: 'Price',
                //     style: {
                //         color: '#666',
                //     }
                // },
            },

            yAxis: {
                gridLineWidth: 0.1,
                // tickPixelInterval:500,
                // minorTickInterval: 'auto',
                // minorTickColor: '#FEFEFE',
                title: {
                    text: '',
                    // style: {
                    //     color: '#666',
                    // }
                },
            },

            legend: {
                symbolWidth: 12,
                symbolRadius: 60,
                align: 'center',
                verticalAlign: 'bottom',
                //y: 500,
                floating: true,
                backgroundColor: '#262c38',
                itemStyle: {
                    color: '#666'
                },
                itemHoverStyle: {
                    color: '#999'
                }
            },
            plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    lineWidth: 1,
                    animation: true,
                    marker: {
                        enabled: false,
                        symbol: 'circle',
                        states: {
                            hover: {
                                enabled: true
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
                crosshairs: [true, true],
                formatter: function () {
                    return 'Price <b>' + this.x + '</b> <br/>' + this.series.name + '<b>' + this.y + '</b>';
                }
            },
            series: [
                {
                    name: 'Buy orders',
                    data: depthChartJSON.bids,
                    color: 'rgba(1,170,120,1.0)',
                    fillColor: 'rgba(1,170,120,0.2)'
                },
                {
                    name: 'Sell orders',
                    data: depthChartJSON.asks,
                    color: 'rgba(255,95,115,1.0)',
                    fillColor: 'rgba(255,95,115,0.2)'
                }
            ]
        });
    });
});
```

}